# Multiple databases with shared structure in JPA

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I'm making a web service (in Spring Boot) with my friends where organizations can join and by joining each organization gets its own database, which is generated on the fly. The reason that every organization has a different database, is that the individual database consists of multiple tables that have unique data only for that organization and **isolation is needed**.

The database structure/schema should be shared among all companies and every change we do (for example add/edit a column or a table) should take effect in all the current databases without disrupting the already present data.

Also, we should be able to query every organization together to get a listing of booked times, names etc on one page with different organizations. Is it possible to achieve this with JPA or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: All your requirements show that you shouldn't have one database by company, but instead have everything in a single database (with company being one of the tables).

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear on that. The reason that every organization has a different database, is that the individual database consists of multiple tables that have unique data only for that organization. I've edited my question.

Comment: Well, you'll need to change that, too, and introduce a foreign key in those tables referencing the ID of an organization.

Comment: The following links might prove useful: https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Multitenant, https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html, http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jpa/multitenancy.html